# Getting Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException exception while performing load test with single system and also in distributed

Tags: jmeter, connection-timeout, connection-reset

We are trying to test a web application with 5k+ users, but we are getting below errors.

•   Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException/Non HTTP response message: Connect to beta.headlite.com:443 [beta.headlite.com/xx.xx.xxx.xx] failed: Connection timed out: connect
•   Non HTTP response code: java.net.BindException/Non HTTP response message: Address already in use: connect
•   Non-HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException/Non HTTP response message: Read timed out
•   Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException/Non HTTP response message: Connection reset **(Most of the samples getting failed with this error)**

We have changed below setting in the properties file and also increased Heap memory to 12GB
**User.Properties file**
**--------------------**

```
`server.rmi.ssl.disable=True`
`mode=Standard`
`jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true`
`httpclient4.retrycount=3`
`hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters`
`http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true`
`httpclient.timeout=300000`
```

**Jmeter.Properties file**
**--------------------**

```
`httpsampler.max_redirects=20 httpclient4.retrycount=1`
`httpclient.timeout=300000`
`https.sessioncontext.shared=true`
`https.default.protocol=TLSv1.2`
`https.socket.protocols=TLSv1 TLSv1.2`
`https.use.cached.ssl.context=true`
```

**HC parameters file**
**--------------------**

```
`http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true`
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `Connection timed out: connect` means that your application cannot respond within the bounds of the timeout, you need to increase it in i.e. [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request)
2. `: java.net.BindException/Non HTTP response message: Address already in use` - most probably you've run out of [free ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/default-dynamic-port-range-tcpip-chang)
3. `Connection reset` - most probably it's connected with point 1, if you believe that the system under test is to blame - you can try implementing workarounds from [JMeterSocketClosed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki page

Comment: We have set timeout  `httpclient.timeout=300000` to user and jmeter properties files.

Mainly we got connection reset error : javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException/Non HTTP response message: Read timed out • Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException/Non HTTP response message: Connection reset

Also we have changed all settings from this link : JMeterSocketClosed

Still above issue is not resolved.